# DateDiff asc and desc

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    at.AccountId AS AccountId, 
    a.FirstName + ' ' + a.LastName AS [FullName],
    DATEDIFF(day, T.ArrivalDate, T.ReturnDate) AS LongestTrip,
    DATEDIFF(day, T.ArrivalDate, T.ReturnDate) AS ShortestTrip  
FROM 
    Accounts a
JOIN 
    AccountsTrips at ON a.Id = AT.AccountId
JOIN 
    Trips t ON T.Id = AT.TripId
WHERE 
    a.MiddleName IS NULL AND t.CancelDate IS NULL
ORDER BY 
    DATEDIFF(day, T.ArrivalDate, T.ReturnDate) DESC, ShortestTrip ASC
```

The code only orders the tables descending in `LongestTrip` and in `ShortestTrip`

SAMPLE DATA !

Find the longest and shortest trip for each account, in days. Filter the results to accounts with no middle name and trips, which are not cancelled (CancelDate is null).

Order the results by Longest Trip days (descending), then by Shortest Trip (ascending).

Examples

```
AccountId   FullName             LongestTrip    ShortestTrip
------------------------------------------------------------
    40      Winna Maisey             7              1
    56      Tillie Windress          7              1
    57      Eadith Gull              7              1
    66      Sargent Rockhall         7              1
    69      Jerome Flory             7              2
     …  …   …   …
```

The Tables are --

```
CREATE TABLE Cities
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Name NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CountryCode CHAR(2) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Hotels
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Name NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    CityId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Cities(Id) NOT NULL,
    EmployeeCount INT NOT NULL,
    BaseRate DECIMAL(10,2)
)

CREATE TABLE Rooms
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Price DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    Type NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Beds INT NOT NULL,
    HotelId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Hotels(Id) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Trips
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    RoomId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Rooms(Id) NOT NULL,
    BookDate DATE NOT NULL, CHECK(BookDate<ArrivalDate),
    ArrivalDate DATE NOT NULL, CHECK(ArrivalDate<ReturnDate),
    ReturnDate DATE NOT NULL,
    CancelDate DATE
)

CREATE TABLE Accounts
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    MiddleName NVARCHAR(20),
    LastName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CityId INT  NOT NULL,
    BirthDate DATE NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL
   
    CONSTRAINT FK_CityId FOREIGN KEY (CityId)
        REFERENCES Cities(Id)
)

CREATE TABLE AccountsTrips
(
    AccountId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Accounts(Id) NOT NULL,
    TripId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Trips(Id) NOT NULL,
    Luggage INT NOT NULL, CHECK(Luggage >= 0)
)
```

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? It sounds like you want max and min of the datediff calculation.

Comment: Im getting the right result but the order by orders the 2 new columns LongestTrip and ShortestTrip in DESCENDING and i need the LongestTrip in desc and ShortestTrip ASC i think the problem is in the 2 datediffs used in the select

Comment: But those two calculations are identical

Comment: How can i make them not identical then thats my question

Comment: I don't follow the sorting rule. You're supposed to find the shortest and longest trip per account. So you get one row for each account. You can sort the total set on longest or on shortest trip, but both doesn't make any sense

Comment: And you still need `min` `max` and `group by`

Comment: It did work with Min and Max before the DATEDIFF and a group by THANK U !

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be related to the tagged AngularJS. Is this SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You want to pick the longest and shortest trips per account from your data. As all you want to get from the trips is the duration, you can simply aggregate and show `MIN` and `MAX` duration:

```
SELECT
    a.Id AS AccountId, 
    a.FirstName + ' ' + a.LastName AS [FullName],
    MIN(DATEDIFF(day, T.ArrivalDate, T.ReturnDate)) AS LongestTrip,
    MAXD(ATEDIFF(day, T.ArrivalDate, T.ReturnDate)) AS ShortestTrip  
FROM 
    Accounts a
JOIN 
    AccountsTrips at ON a.Id = AT.AccountId
JOIN 
    Trips t ON T.Id = AT.TripId
WHERE 
    a.MiddleName IS NULL AND t.CancelDate IS NULL
GROUP BY
    a.Id, a.FirstName, a.LastName
ORDER BY 
    LongestTrip DESC, ShortestTrip ASC;
```

If you wanted to show additional data from the trips, you would use window functions (probably `MIN OVER` and `MAX OVER`) and would then either show two rows per account or aggregate these two rows.

Comment: @HoneyBadger: Haha, thank you. As to sorting: This sorts all accounts by longest trip duration descending. In case of ties it shows shortest trips first, i.e. the accounts with the widest gap. Sounds okay for me.

Comment: ah yes, of course. Got my head on wrong way I guess.